# Can IntelliSense be made accent insensitive?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I am maintaining an old piece of C# code written in Spanish, originally in VS2008, containing names with accented letters where appropriate according to the grammar rules of the Spanish language.

Regarding compilation and execution everything is fine, but I have noticed that, in VS2008, intellisense was somewhat accent insensitive; if I had a property named `Índice` and typed an accentless i, it would nevertheless suggest the name I was aiming at. That is not the case in VS2017, where accented letters seem to be considered as completely different from the same letters without accents.

Is this behaviour configurable? Section `Text editor > C# > IntelliSense` in the settings window does not seem to contain any relevant parameters, and while I have exported my settings to a file and examined the resulting XML, I cannot find any configuration parameters whose names contain the substrings "Accent" or "Sensit".